# SQL: Select only rows fullfilling conditions via relation table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and I need to select values from first only when all certain conditions are met in second table. Let explain more on an example.

**First table**

```
id       movie    
---|--------------
1  | Matrix       
2  | Pulp Fiction 
3  | Avengers     
4  | Commando
```

**Second table**

```
id    movie_id    user_id
---|-----------|---
1  | 1         |  1
2  | 1         |  2
3  | 1         |  3
4  | 2         |  1
5  | 2         |  4
6  | 3         |  2
7  | 4         |  1
8  | 4         |  3
```

And from those tables I need to find out only movies, that user 1 and 3 have seen. So in result I need to see

**Wanted result**

```
id    movie   
---|--------
1  | Matrix      
4  | Commando
```

I tried some queries, but cannot get a grasp of final result.
In the end I will be ***"construncting"*** this query based on users selected as input. So in the end, there might be as well 5 users and I will need to find only movies, all of them have seen. So please bear that in mind.

All help and ideas are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select b.id, b.movie from 
Secondtable a inner join Firsttable b 
on a.movie_id=b.id 
where user_id in (1,3)
group by b.id, b.movie
having count(distinct user_id)=2
```

Comment: ... thanks, works exactly as I need :) (+ you fixed the wrong ID in intended result :D )

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `group by` and `having`:

```
select t1.id, t1.name
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.movie_id
where t2.user_id in (1, 3)
group by t1.id, t1.name
having count(*) = 2;
```

This approach is quite flexible in the logic it can implement -- basically by changing the `having` clause.

The alternative I would suggest without aggregation uses `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where exists (select 1
              from t2
              where t2.movie_id = t1.id and t2.user_id = 1
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from t2
              where t2.movie_id = t1.id and t2.user_id = 3
             );
```

With an index on `t2(movie_id, user_id)`, this probably has the best performance of any alternatives.

Comment: ... thanks for second possible approach. I choosed @fa06 only because he was slightly faster. Both of you gave me exactly what I needed and it works, now I only need to choose which one will work better for my specific usecase ;)

Comment: @Yoshi . . . I would not have answered if I had seen fa06's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to complete this.Just use join clause.As below:

```
select
    distinct b.user_id,a.move
from
    table1 a
join
    table2 b on a.id = b.movie_id and b.user_id in (1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JOIN to get related data from 2 tables (based on ID) and filter results with WHERE condition

```
SELECT secondTable.id, firstTable.movie
FROM secondTable
JOIN firstTable ON secondTable.movie_id = firstTable.id
WHERE secondTable.user_id IN (1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

DISTINCT statement is used to return only different values.

You can try this. I used table name as Firsttable and Secondtable

```
select DISTINCT f.id, f.movie from Firsttable f join Secondtable s on f.id = s.movie_id 
where s.user_id in (1, 3)
```